# How to display the data in the one of router in angular?

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have designed the router in the main component:

```
<div class="main-panel">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

In the `app-navbar` there is a `search box`, and search result display at a  component in the router-outlet. Problem is that I don't know how to pass the data to router-outlet from navbar component .

I even tried to import the component, but the router-outlet cannot auto refresh boolean changed.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I checked this link, I think it is only working with parent to child or child to parent. in the router-outer is not working with.

Comment: @Jae.Lin look at the part about communication via services. P.S. if you inject the service in the root, all components will be able to access the service

Comment: @ХристиянХристов thank you very much for your hint, let me try. I think it will work, but the component will update (auto refresh) *ngif condition with to access the service?

Comment: It depends on how are you using the service, if you implement the communication via Subjects and subscriptions (as explained in the docs) the components should update on their own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to build a service. [I provided several other options in my original answer ... but it was deleted by a moderator so I'm leaving those other options off.]

I worked up a stackblitz demonstrating how to use a service **IN THIS SPECIFIC SCENARIO** here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simpleservice-deborahk

NOTE: It does NOT require `Subject` or subscriptions

It provides a "header" component similar to your `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` with a search box. And a `<router-outlet>` with a component displaying the result of the search. (Though my specific example only shows the search text ... it could easily be extended to use that search text to display the search results.)

I hope it is of help to you!

Comment: I think I did not delete your post, and I appreciate your answer. It worked !

Comment: Great to hear it helped! No worries ... you didn't delete it. A moderator did. I used a similar answer to another question so they deleted it ... My focus here is on trying to help the one person with the question ... I sometimes forget the rules for the many. :-)

Comment: one more question, In your stackblitz example, you used the ngModel to make two way binding.  if in my routed component, I just want to use ngif to check search box submitted the request,and display the data in the routed component. how to tell the ngif keep listen the service data changed. I think the ngModel cannot working with ngif. for example search box sent request. other component check ngif and display data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you fork the stackblitz and change it how you need? Then post the link to your forked version and I'll take a look.

Comment: <h1>Results</h1>
    <!--
      in this div, I wannt to add a condition to display it. for example, if user enter 
      value and submitted. the div will be true for display 
      -->
    <div  *ngif = "???"  >This component would display the list using:
        {{ searchTerm }}
    </div>    I think I did not know how to folk in the stackbliz, newcomer to use it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "submitted". Do you mean that the search would require the user to click an "OK" button of some type before displaying the routed results?

Comment: yes, you get my means, I did not know how to make ngif keep listen the data from the service.

Comment: How about this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simpleservice-deborahk-q2bsz7